# mac svn client can't commit to tortoise svn server

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I'm trying to use svn 1.6 with my Xcode projects on lion. The server is a tortoise svn server on windows. I can check out the projects with no problem, but when I go to commit I get the error that

> svn: Commit failed (details follow): svn: Can't get exclusive lock on file '/Volumes/SVN_Repository/Mobile/db/txn-current-lock': Operation not supported

The repository is fine. When I go to commit something to the same place with my windows client it works great. The windows client is 1.6.11 and the mac client is 1.6.12 I wouldn't think that would be that big of a deal.

Is there a way to make the mac client work nicely with the windows server?

Thanks

Comment: [Might this be the issue here?](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-01/0982.shtml)

Comment: If the server is really a windows server which is path starting with "/" that looks more like a unix machine. Or is this a kind of NAS etc. which will not work with SVN. How is the Server installed? Apache, visualSVN server ? Can you give a litte bit more information about that.

Comment: it starts with the / because it's mounted over the network. The actual command I use to checkout is  

svn checkout "file:///Volumes/SVN_Repository/Mobile/root/Stage Monitor - iPad/branches/nick - clean warnings" /Users/nlong/Desktop/ssp/StageMonitor2
  As far as I know, it's just a raw tortoise install. However, when I installed visual svn I can checkout and commit to another server. Is visual svn the easiest route?

Comment: @DanielBeck I was hopeful, but no. I specified my domain username and password, which is an administrator, and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **NEVER** use file:/// protocol for accessing repo or working copy on shared drive
2. Install (any) good SVN-server with **authenticated access**
3. Configure server and use it without headache of lame workflow

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is a Subversion client. Whilst it does include the svnserve server, you will need to [manually configure that](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html). You may want to have a look at [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/download), which allows you to configure an Apache Subversion webserver so that you can access your repository via http://